# Docker container redirects to the wrong url

Tags: .net, docker, model-view-controller

I've created a docker windows container from the sample image from dockerhub:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample --network cn -v C:\src\:C:\src mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
```

The container runs fine and I can browse the sample app at http://localhost:8000.

Now, I have a webapp running on my local IIS at port 63330 which I can browse without problem.
I copied the source files from that webapp to C:\src and from within the container terminal, I removed the contents of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ and replaced it with the files from C:\src. Then when I browse again the http://localhost:8000, it removes the port 8000 like http://localhost/Login.
My local IIS does not have that problem and it redirects to http://localhost:63330/Login.

I'm running out of ideas already...need help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port mapping from 8000:80 to 8000:63330?

Comment: Hi Paul Digz, thanks for your reply, Yes, I tried it all. The thing that fixed my problem was I modified the Web.config file that has a key that forces to use https instead of http. I stopped my local IIS and use port 80 instead on both docker container and host. -p 80:80 and it worked.